# Docker Image not able to find main file in jar

Tags: java, docker

Trying to create docker image and run jar file in it.Running the docker image gives me
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 1000.00M
    Ergonomics Machine Class: server
    Using VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Error: Could not find or load main class Application

I tried adding manifest in pom.Nothing helps.Running jar file alone using java -jar commands doesnot give this error.

DockerFile:

```
ADD /document-ws/target/document-service-v2-ws.jar /app/document-service-app.jar
RUN chmod 644 /app/document-service-app.jar
```

Comment: How do you execute the JAR file within your container?

Comment: You haven't shown us the actual CMD commands in your Dockerfile. Are you doing CMD java -jar /app... ? Or are you just doin gCMD /app... ? I think the java -jar might be more successful, but I haven't tested the other way.

Comment: using this command :
```docker run -e APP_ENV=dev -p 83:8080 *image name*```

Comment: @jboockmann
running the above command should automatically run the jar but here it is not able to find the main class

Comment: If this is about a Spring Boot application, you might want to look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/ for more info.

Comment: @PriyaSaloni based on your provided Dockerfile the image will do nothing, because you lack a CMD entry. Have you tried entering the container and execute the jar file manually?